# SQLite Expert Personal как создать базу данных

Tags: sqlite

Добрый день!
Хочу в SQLite Expert Personal создать базу данных. Выбираю в пункте меню "file - new database" и вместо окна первоначальных настроек бд открывается окно для выбора файла. Собственно как создать БД в SQLite Expert Personal?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так и должно быть. Сначала надо выбрать расположение файла базы данных, а уже потом можно будет изменить свойства базы.

Comment: Так я же хочу создать файл, а программа просит меня его выбрать, а как его выбрать если его у меня нет.

Comment: Программа не просит Вас выбрать имя существующего файла. Вы можете выбрать несуществующий файл, а можете создать файл нулевого размера и выбрать его.

Comment: добавил скрин, вот честно не понимаю, что мне нужно сделать

Comment: В поле "Имя файла" вписываете имя файла, а потом нажимаете "Открыть".

Comment: я в шоке))))спасибо!!!